# Sankey in R: set constant height left to right

Tags: r, height, width, sankey-diagram

> I want to create a sankey that describes whether people are retained in care, lost to follow up, died or censored at each year after they started treatment.
> I have created the diagram but the buckets at each time point get larger/ taller from left to right.
> This is my code:

```
ret_pharm_sankey_5yearall <- sankeyNetwork(Links = retention_pharm_sankey_5yrall_df, Nodes = retention_nodes,
                                           Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                                           Value = "time_year", NodeID = "name", 
                                           colourScale = my_colour, 
                                           LinkGroup = "group", 
                                           NodeGroup="group", 
                                           iterations = 0,  #this uses the order in nodes dataframe
                                           sinksRight=FALSE)
```

What I want: I want it to remain a constant height, reflecting the consistent number of individuals, over time
What I've tried:

1. I have tried setting sinksRight to true/false and it doesnt help.
2. tried this from chat gpt:

```
# Add CSS styling to set constant height
ret_pharm_sankey_5yearall <- onRender(ret_pharm_sankey_5yearall, '
  function(el, x) {
    d3.select(el).select("svg").style("height", "500px");
  }
')
```

What I get:
[Sankey diagram of RIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXv98.png)

If more helpful to see it visually, i want the Sankey to be a consistent width representing a constant number of people, like this: [example of what I want the Sankey to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZafI.png)

instead of this:
[Sankey diagram of RIC that I produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXv98.png)
(which starts small and grows larger, despite containing a consistent number of individuals at each time point)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry, I tried to give an example but I think its less about the data and more about a setting - tried to explain better visually. Let me know if that doesnt help make it clearer!